# Как правильно передать настройки сервера в WildFly 9 на другую машину?

Tags: java-ee, настройки, wildfly

Доброго времени суток, как правильно передать\выгрузить настройки в WildFly 9, чтобы потом их было легко и комфортно применить\импортировать на другой машине?

Пробовал так:
- копирую файл standalone-*.xml. Переименовываю в свой, прикрепляю к исходникам и на пустой машине запускаю командой:

```
./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-(full)-myProject.xml
```

Далее встал вопрос как правильно выгрузить установленный модуль для MySQL? На своей машине я настроил по этой статье как модуль: http://hpehl.info/jdbc-driver-setup.html

Answer (score 3):

Простой способ установить модуль - это использовать **Command Line Interface** (CLI):

Пример для **postgresql** драйвера:

Открываем `jboss-cli.bat` (под linux это `jboss-cli.sh`) находится в каталоге `%JBOSS_HOME%/bin` и выполняем команду:

module add —name=org.postgres —resources=E:\TMP\postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar —dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api

В данном случае 
`—name=org.postgres` - имя модуля

`—resources=E:\TMP\postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar` - путь к Jar архиву с драйвером

**Для mysql все аналогично. Изменится имя и путь к драйверу.**

По идее, на этом можно остановиться, если Вы перенесли `standalone.xml` с одного сервера на другой.

Но можно не переносить `standalone.xml`, а так же через **CLI** создать необходимый `Datasource`

*Команда для регистрации драйвера:*

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=postgres:add(driver-name="postgres",driver-module-name="org.postgres",driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver)
```

*Команда для регистрации Datasource:*

```
data-source add —jndi-name=java:/LiferayDS —name=LiferayPool —connection-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/liferay —driver-name=postgres —user-name=dbuser —password=dbuserpwd
```

В эти команды следует внести изменения под mysql. В драйвере поменяется class на `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` название и имя модуля.